# How to replace args from docker to singularity?

Tags: docker, terminal, singularity-container

I am trying to pull a docker image but have to use singularity. How can I do this? Here is the script I am running.

```
cp -rp ~/adversarial-policies/ $SLURM_TMPDIR
cd adversarial-policies/
singularity pull docker://humancompatibleai/adversarial_policies:latest
singularity run -it --env MUJOCO_KEY=~/.mujoco/mjkey.txt ./adversarial_policies-latest.simg 
source ./modelfreevenv/bin/activate
python -m modelfree.multi.train with paper --path $SLURM_TMPDIR --data-path $SLURM_TMPDIR
cp $SLURM_TMPDIR/job-output.txt /network/tmp1/gomrokma/
cp $SLURM_TMPDIR/error.txt /network/tmp1/gomrokma/
```

The errors I get are with `ERROR: Unknown option: --build-arg`
`ERROR: Unknown option: -it`.

Any help would be appreciated. I am new to using singularity containers instead of docker

Answer (score 0):

Singularity and Docker are both containers, but they are not a drop in replacement for each other. I *strongly* recommend reading [the documentation](https://sylabs.io/docs/) of the relevant version of the singularity you're using. The latest version has a good section on [using docker and singularity together](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.4/user-guide/singularity_and_docker.html#making-use-of-public-images-from-docker-hub).

---

If you are using singularity v3 or newer, the file created from `singularity pull` will be named `adversarial_policies_latest.sif`, not `adversarial_policies-latest.simg`. If v2 is the only version available on your cluster, ask the admins to install the v3. 2.6.1 is the only v2 without security issues and it is no longer getting any  updates.

As for the `singularity run ...`, the `-it` docker options are to force an interactive tty session rather than run in the background. `singularity exec` and `singularity run` both will always run in the foreground, so there is no equivalent required option to use with singularity. Passing environment variables is also handled differently. Since the container is run as your user, it passes your environment through to it. You can either set `export MUJOCO_KEY=~/.mujoco/mjkey.txt` further up the script or have it set just for the command: `MUJOCO_KEY=~/.mujoco/mjkey.txt singularity run ./adversarial_policies-latest.simg`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I adjusted my code according to your recommendations. I am now getting ```ERROR: Image file exists, not overwriting. ^[[91mERROR  : Unknown image format/type: ./adversarial_policies-latest.simg``` Any idea what this one means? I tried with .sif but it does not recognize that path. I found online that using ```--force``` can solve the issue but I'm not sure where to implement it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my clusters use v2 and won't be able to update.

Comment: The overwrite warning suggests that a file exists with the expected name, but the next error says it's not in the correct format. If you can, check that the file exists and that it was built correctly. Using `--force` in the pull is okay, it will just overwrite an existing file. You can also try building the image locally, and compare the file size with the image on cluster. If they're different, odds are good there was a problem in the `pull` step and you'll need to check the job output log to figure out what happened.